# Import osmnx to python

Tags: python, osmnx

I'm trying to use the osmnx package in Python. I followed the steps given in https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and I now have an enviorment in anconda with the given package.

But, when I try to import this package to python with:

> `import osmnx`

I get an error saying:

> `No module named 'osmnx'`

Could anyone help me with this?
Thank you!

Comment: Is your anaconda environment active when you try to import osmnx? If it's active, is it the same environment that has osmnx installed?

Comment: @AndrasDeak how do i know if my anconda enviorment is active? i'm quite new at python. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**edit** - another solution:

try
`conda install osmnx` and then `conda install gdal=2.4.4`

---

try creating a new full env for OSMnx:

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
```

then activate that environment using:

```
(base) C:\Users\User>conda activate ox
```

to test for successful installation run

```
(ox) C:\Users\User>python
>>> import osmnx as ox
```

Comment: And i run all this in the anaconda prompt?

Comment: from your terminal

Comment: when i run it in the terminal i get: 'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file. 
And when i run it on the console i get No module named 'osmnx.

Comment: hm, you can try running everything in anaconda

Comment: Oh! I got it, but when i run the "import osmnx as ox" in the ox, nothing seems to happen, this means the download occured successfully?

Comment: yes, try using it and see if it works